# How to build aseprite executable

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015, nmake

I am trying to compile aseprite using this tutorial here https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md

I have installed Windows 10 SDK and Visual Studio 2015

I am using the CMake GUI because I am not familiar with using the command line at all

This is the CMake Log

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Looking for include file stdint.h
Looking for include file stdint.h - found
Performing Test HAVE_STDINT_H
Performing Test HAVE_STDINT_H - Success
Performing Test HAVE_SCHED_YIELD
Performing Test HAVE_SCHED_YIELD - Failed
Performing Test ASEPRITE_LITTLE_ENDIAN
Performing Test ASEPRITE_LITTLE_ENDIAN - Success
Found DXGUID: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.10586.0/um/x64/dxguid.lib  
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of off64_t
Check size of off64_t - failed
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Looking for include file dlfcn.h
Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
Looking for include file fcntl.h
Looking for include file fcntl.h - found
Looking for include file gl/gl.h
Looking for include file gl/gl.h - not found
Looking for include file inttypes.h
Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
Looking for include file memory.h
Looking for include file memory.h - found
Looking for include file rle.h
Looking for include file rle.h - not found
Looking for include file stdarg.h
Looking for include file stdarg.h - found
Looking for include file stdlib.h
Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
Looking for include file strings.h
Looking for include file strings.h - not found
Looking for include file string.h
Looking for include file string.h - found
Looking for include file sys/stat.h
Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
Looking for include file unistd.h
Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
Looking for include file varargs.h
Looking for include file varargs.h - found
Looking for include file X11/Xlib.h
Looking for include file X11/Xlib.h - not found
Looking for include file X11/Xutil.h
Looking for include file X11/Xutil.h - not found
Looking for vprintf
Looking for vprintf - not found
Looking for _doprnt
Looking for _doprnt - not found
Looking for strdup
Looking for strdup - found
curl version=[7.21.6]
wldap32 not found CURL_DISABLE_LDAP set ON
Looking for getch in ws2_32;
Looking for getch in ws2_32; - found
Looking for getch in winmm;ws2_32
Looking for getch in winmm;ws2_32 - found
Looking for cldap_open in wldap32
Looking for cldap_open in wldap32 - found
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenSSL NOT Found, disabling CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL
Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;ws2_32;winmm
Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;ws2_32;winmm - not found
Looking for ldap_init in ldap;ws2_32;winmm
Looking for ldap_init in ldap;ws2_32;winmm - not found
Looking for include file ws2tcpip.h
Looking for include file ws2tcpip.h - found
Looking for include files ws2tcpip.h, winsock2.h
Looking for include files ws2tcpip.h, winsock2.h - found
Looking for 3 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdio.h
Looking for 3 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdio.h - found
Looking for 4 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., windows.h
Looking for 4 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., windows.h - found
Looking for 5 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., winsock.h
Looking for 5 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., winsock.h - found
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/filio.h
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/filio.h - not found
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/ioctl.h
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/ioctl.h - not found
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/resource.h
Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/resource.h - not found
Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/uio.h
Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/uio.h - not found
Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/un.h
Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/un.h - not found
Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., arpa/tftp.h
Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., arpa/tftp.h - not found
Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., assert.h
Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., assert.h - found
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., crypto.h
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., crypto.h - not found
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., des.h
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., des.h - not found
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., err.h
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., err.h - not found
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., errno.h
Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., errno.h - found
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi.h
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi.h - not found
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_generic.h
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_generic.h - not found
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h - not found
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idn-free.h
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idn-free.h - not found
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ifaddrs.h
Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ifaddrs.h - not found
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., krb.h
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., krb.h - not found
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libgen.h
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libgen.h - not found
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libssh2.h
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libssh2.h - not found
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., limits.h
Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., limits.h - found
Looking for 14 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., locale.h
Looking for 14 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., locale.h - found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., netinet/tcp.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., netinet/tcp.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/crypto.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/crypto.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/engine.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/engine.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/err.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/err.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/pem.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/pem.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/pkcs12.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/pkcs12.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/rsa.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/rsa.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/ssl.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/ssl.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/x509.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., openssl/x509.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., pem.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., pem.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., poll.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., poll.h - not found
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., rsa.h
Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., rsa.h - not found
Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ssl.h
Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ssl.h - not found
Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdbool.h
Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdbool.h - found
Looking for 21 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stropts.h
Looking for 21 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stropts.h - not found
Looking for 22 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., tld.h
Looking for 22 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., tld.h - not found
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ldap.h
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ldap.h - not found
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/utsname.h
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/utsname.h - not found
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idna.h
Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idna.h - not found
LDAP_H not found CURL_DISABLE_LDAP set ON
Check size of size_t
Check size of size_t - done
Check size of ssize_t
Check size of ssize_t - failed
Check size of long long
Check size of long long - done
Check size of long
Check size of long - done
Check size of short
Check size of short - done
Check size of int
Check size of int - done
Check size of __int64
Check size of __int64 - done
Check size of time_t
Check size of time_t - done
Looking for basename
Looking for basename - not found
Looking for strncmpi
Looking for strncmpi - not found
Looking for alarm
Looking for alarm - not found
Looking for gethostbyname
Looking for gethostbyname - found
Looking for strtoll
Looking for strtoll - found
Looking for _strtoi64
Looking for _strtoi64 - found
Looking for strerror_r
Looking for strerror_r - not found
Looking for siginterrupt
Looking for siginterrupt - not found
Looking for fork
Looking for fork - not found
Looking for freeaddrinfo
Looking for freeaddrinfo - found
Looking for freeifaddrs
Looking for freeifaddrs - not found
Looking for pipe
Looking for pipe - not found
Looking for ftruncate
Looking for ftruncate - not found
Looking for getprotobyname
Looking for getprotobyname - found
Looking for getrlimit
Looking for getrlimit - not found
Looking for idn_free
Looking for idn_free - not found
Looking for idna_strerror
Looking for idna_strerror - not found
Looking for tld_strerror
Looking for tld_strerror - not found
Looking for setlocale
Looking for setlocale - found
Looking for setrlimit
Looking for setrlimit - not found
Looking for fcntl
Looking for fcntl - not found
Looking for ioctl
Looking for ioctl - not found
Looking for setsockopt
Looking for setsockopt - found
Looking for inet_pton
Looking for inet_pton - not found
Performing Curl Test HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK
Performing Curl Test HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET - Success
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL_FIONBIO
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL_FIONBIO - Success
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_FIONBIO
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_FIONBIO - Success
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_FIONBIO
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_FIONBIO - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_SIOCGIFADDR
Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_SIOCGIFADDR - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_SETSOCKOPT_SO_NONBLOCK
Performing Curl Test HAVE_SETSOCKOPT_SO_NONBLOCK - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SIN6_SCOPE_ID
Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SIN6_SCOPE_ID - Failed
CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:562 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME" will no longer be dereferenced
  when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD
  behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:664 (curl_internal_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKLEN_T
Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKLEN_T - Success
Performing Curl Test HAVE_BOOL_T
Performing Curl Test HAVE_BOOL_T - Success
Performing Curl Test HAVE_FILE_OFFSET_BITS
Performing Curl Test HAVE_FILE_OFFSET_BITS - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R
Performing Curl Test HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R - Failed
Performing Curl Test HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R
Performing Curl Test HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R - Failed
Check size of curl_off_t
Check size of curl_off_t - failed
Check size of socklen_t
Check size of socklen_t - done
Performing Test curl_cv_recv
Performing Test curl_cv_recv - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMake/CurlCheckCSourceCompiles.cmake:16 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "curl_cv_func_recv_test" will no longer be
  dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
  the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMake/OtherTests.cmake:47 (curl_check_c_source_compiles)
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:792 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Success
Performing Test curl_cv_send
Performing Test curl_cv_send - Success
Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)
Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Success
Performing Test HAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL
Performing Test HAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEVAL
Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEVAL - Success
Performing Test HAVE_POLL_FINE
Performing Test HAVE_POLL_FINE - Failed
Check size of sig_atomic_t
Check size of sig_atomic_t - done
Performing Test HAVE_SIG_ATOMIC_T_NOT_VOLATILE
Performing Test HAVE_SIG_ATOMIC_T_NOT_VOLATILE - Success
Check size of struct sockaddr_storage
Check size of struct sockaddr_storage - failed
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Creating directory F:/aseprite/aseprite-source/build/third_party/freetype2/include/freetype/config
Creating file F:/aseprite/aseprite-source/build/third_party/freetype2/include/freetype/config/ftconfig.h
Creating file F:/aseprite/aseprite-source/build/third_party/freetype2/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h
Performing Test WORDS_BIGENDIAN
Performing Test WORDS_BIGENDIAN - Failed
Configuring done
Generating done
```

[These are the files CMake created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCvJ2.png)

There's no bin folder where I can locate the executable file

I think I am just missing this step rather than doing something wrong

> After you have executed one of the `cmake .. -G <generator>` commands, you have to compile the project executing make, nmake, opening the solution, etc.

I tried using developer prompt for visual studio but this is what I get

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd F:\aseprite\aseprite-source\build

C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmake aseprite

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'aseprite'
Stop.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmake /f aseprite PREFIX="F:\aseprite\aseprite-source\build"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'aseprite' not found
Stop.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmake /f aseprite.sln PREFIX="F:\aseprite\aseprite-source\build"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'aseprite.sln' not found
Stop.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmake /f aseprite.sln

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'aseprite.sln' not found
Stop.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I have already googled for about 3 hours and I am not understanding what I am supposed to do next I apologize but this is my first time compiling a program so I am kind of walking blind

Comment: Add a target probably?

Comment: ***I have already googled for about 3 hours and I am not understanding what I am supposed to do next*** I would spend a few minutes to learn what the command line is and how to use it. Then the other steps will make much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake is used for configuration and generation of build system / IDE projects in a mostly compiler and platform agnostic way.

From what you posted it seems that you have used the `Visual Studio` generator, when you clicked `Configure` in Cmake-gui.

This generated the project files, the solution file and all the bells and whistles you need open it in `Visual Studio` (simply by double clicking on the .sln file usually). I haven't used `CMake` in such a way, but if I'm not mistaken, you can build the project from within Visual Studio (everything should be set).

Alternatively (the more command line way), is to use a different generator. For that you need to start from a different `build` directory or delete the current one, since you cannot change the generator after `CMake`'s initial configuration has run.
It seems `NMake` should work for you (I don't have it on my system). After you ran the configuration again in a different directory using the `NMake Makefiles` generator, simply navigate there in a command window (probably developer prompt can work too), and issue the command:

```
nmake
```

This should build aseprite for you, and you'll find `aseprite.exe` in the `bin` folder.

EDIT: [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797362/5114859) has the other key to your problem, you haven't changed drives, and as he points out, `msbuild` can be used to build Visual Studio solutions from command line.

Comment: I built the project inside visual studio using the aseprite.sln file but it failed, http://pastebin.com/XXFGfRNQ This is the output do you have any suggestions? @Mohammad

Comment: It looks like libcurl was built but not in ..\lib\..\libcurl.lib. Does libcurl.lib exist? Did you try running the build a second time? Is lib a subfolder of aseprite\aseprite-source\build?

Comment: @dresherjm Yes I tried it again and I got the same errors, http://imgur.com/Hm5KMvS

Answer (score 2):

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd F:\aseprite\aseprite-source\build` had no effect since you are not on `F` drive as you can see in the next line prompt:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmake aseprite`

Try this sequence:

```
f:
cd F:\aseprite\aseprite-source\build
msbuild aseprite.sln
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to make it work

To fix this error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\lib..\libcurl.lib'

I had to copy and paste the libcurl.lib library from build/lib to build like it said here https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/788

After that I tried building again and I got this error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64\dxguid.lib : warning LNK4272: library
>   machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

So I deleted the build folder, changed my generator in CMake from "Visual Studio 14 2015" to "Visual Studio 14 2015 x64", generated everything again, repeated step 1 and rebuilt it one last time in visual studio and it finally created the aseprite.exe file

Comment: ***Visual Studio 14 2015*** That is a 32 bit build while ***Visual Studio 14 2015 x64*** is a 64 bit build.